# Reverting problems caused by checkinstall with gcc build

Tags: package-management, gcc, install-from-source, checkinstall

I recently downloaded the GCC 4.6.2 source in order to play around a bit with C++11. Having been told about [checkinstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) and its usefulness in installing programs from source, I created a Debian package from the install using `sudo checkinstall -D make install`.

Wanting to see how well the newly created package worked, I removed it using Synaptic Package Manager. As it turns out, the package checkinstall created from `make install` tried to remove every single file the installation process touched, including shared gcc libraries like /lib64/libgcc_s.so. Despite not being able to run a bunch of programs due to this missing dependency, I was able to restore my system back to normal by reinstalling the package from command line using `dpkg`.

At this point I want to remove the package from the package manager since it's so dangerous, but ***not*** remove the installed files. I was looking around in /var/lib/dpkg and found that the package manager seems to be based on text files which list packages and such - can I just remove all mention of the package from the files in /var/lib/dpkg, or is there a safer way to go about this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies - I've added the answer.

Comment: [That answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/267583/22949) (by the OP) is substantive and may well help others. Therefore, this is not too localized, and should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up manually removing mention of the package from the files in `/var/lib/dpkg`. Things continued working normally after this was done.