# Build .deb package from source, without installing it

Tags: package-management, packaging, install-from-source, checkinstall

Suppose I have an installer program or source tarball for some program I want to install. (There is no Debian package available.) First I want to create a `.deb` package out of it, in order to be able to cleanly remove the installed program in the future (see [Uninstalling application built from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22510/uninstalling-application-built-from-source), [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)). Also, installing using a package prevents it from clobbering files from other packages, which cannot be guaranteed if you run the installer or `sudo make install`.

#### Checkinstall

From reading the answers there and elsewhere, I gather the usual solution is to use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to build the package. Unfortunately, it seems `checkinstall` does *not* prevent `make install` from clobbering system files from other packages. For example, according to [Reverting problems caused by checkinstall with gcc build](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73192/reverting-problems-caused-by-checkinstall-with-gcc-build):

> I created a Debian package from the install using `sudo checkinstall -D make install`.
>
> [...] I removed it using Synaptic Package Manager. As it turns out, [removing] the package checkinstall created from `make install` tried to remove every single file the installation process touched, including shared gcc libraries like /lib64/libgcc_s.so.

I then tried to tell `checkinstall` to build the package without installing it, in the hope of bypassing the issue. I created a dummy Makefile:

```
install:
    echo "Bogus" > /bin/qwertyuiop
```

and ran `sudo checkinstall --install=no`. The file `/bin/qwertyuiop` *was* created, even though the package was not installed.

In my case, *I do not trust the installer / `make install` to not overwrite system files*, so this use of `checkinstall` is ruled out.

#### How can I build the package, *without* installing it or letting it touch system files?

Is it possible to run Checkinstall in a [`fakechroot`](https://github.com/fakechroot/fakechroot/wiki)ed [debootstrap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105840/install-program-from-source-to-chroot-env/105849#105849) environment to achieve this? Preferably the build should be done as a normal user rather than root, which would prevent the process from overwriting system files if it goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try out `debuild` to create a binary (deb) file out of source. You would have to prepare the debian folder like you are packaging it. Once you got it right, run the command `debuild -b` from inside the source directory and it will create a deb file for you.

You would also want to take a look at [Introduction to Debian packaging](http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging).

---

If all that is crazy stuff, you would have to just make do with `checkinstall` messing with system files.

Answer (score 1):

I found [an answer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-checkinstall-build-packages-source) in a Linux Journal article called *Using Checkinstall To Build Packages From Source*:

> If you merely want to create the .deb without carrying out the installation, use the command line switch

`sudo checkinstall --install=no`